# Why is my API call for application_number is not working?

Tags: openfda

#1: https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.application_number:ANDA076407

I am trying to make a similar API call to above but for below application#

**New Drug Application (NDA): 212994
Company: COMMCAVE THERAPEUTICS SA**

However I am getting code not found error when using the API call below. Why is call #1 working and #2 not working? What am I doing wrong in call #2?

#2: https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=patient.drug.openfda.application_number:NDA212994

Answer (score 1):

The openFDA drug adverse event API returns data that has been collected from the FDA Adverse Event Reporting System (FAERS),
a database that contains information on adverse events and medication error reports submitted to FDA.

To know more about FAERS, Please go through the below link
https://www.fda.gov/drugs/surveillance/questions-and-answers-fdas-adverse-event-reporting-system-faers

Please find the below link for a more detailed description of the `application_number` field.
https://open.fda.gov/apis/drug/event/searchable-fields

If the FAERS database has the newly reported application number then the openFDA will load the data quarterly basis.
However, please be advised that the data in this API may lag by 3 months or more at any given time, depending on when the quarterly FAERS data is released.

Please check the below page for more recent updates that happened on the drug adverse events dataset in openFDA.
https://open.fda.gov/about/status/